# why does naming a python file ".py" have no highlighting

Tags: python, python-idle

So I was making a python test file called ".py" and I tried typing some code. Then, there was no syntax highlighting. Why does that happen? Also, when I changed the name to "test.py" there was highlighting. I use idle on windows 10 and I also tried on my dad's computer and naming the file ".py" didn't have any highlighting.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverFlow, It's called IDE (without L). Which IDE do you use? You can install Atom, VS Code, Notepadd++, Pycharm (Community version is free) or other IDEs. They have syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Saeed Idle *is* a Python IDE, see the `python-dle` tag.

Comment: If `.py` is the full file name, that's (conventionally) the name of a hidden file, not an empty file name with an extension.

Comment: It looks like it could be a bug in the editor. However, it would be unusual to have a module with no name.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the comment and making me aware of that.

Comment: check the ID(L)E preferences for what syntax checking is turned on. there's probably a list of languages for which it's on.  It's unlikely that Python is off, but possible.

Comment: @FredZimmerman Python's IDLE is a python-only IDE. IDLE treats any file with a '.py' or '.'pyw' extension as a python file, and all code entered in Shell as python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Python files are internally Python *modules*, and the names of *modules* are the string before the `.py`. For example, file `test.py` is a module named `test`.

If you are creating a file named only `.py`, then the module name is essentially nothing, which is not valid.

For further information about naming Python modules or packages, read this: [PEP8 -- Style Guide for Python Code.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#:%7E:text=of%20PEP%203131.-,Package%20and%20Module%20Names,use%20of%20underscores%20is%20discouraged)

---

In addition, for UNIX-like operating systems and modern Windows, files starting with `.` conventionally means *hidden files* that contain configuration information. For example, there is a configuration file for bash called `.bashrc` that runs every time a shell starts.

Comment: `test-foo` isn't a valid module name, either, but most relevant programs should still consider its contents as Python code for syntax highlighting purposes.

Answer (score 2):

This is the idlelib.editor.EditorWindow method deciding if a file being edited is python code.

```
def ispythonsource(self, filename):
    if not filename or os.path.isdir(filename):
        return True
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))
    if os.path.normcase(ext) in (".py", ".pyw"):
        return True
    line = self.text.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')
    return line.startswith('#!') and 'python' in line
```

A file with no name (because new), a .py(w) extension, or magic comment (on unix-like OSes) is assumed to be python.  (Ignore the directory part.)  Here is the behavior of `os.path.splitext`, at least on Windows.

```
>>> os.path.splitext('a.py')
('a', '.py')
>>> os.path.splitext('.py')
('.py', '')
```

`.py` is seen as having no extension, and without a magic comment,  is not seen as python code.  After thinking about it, I am not inclined to add special case code to recognize it, as such a name is a bad idea as explained by others.  This is the first time I have seen this question.

Answer (score 0):

naming a file starting with period does some weird things. in **linux it is a hidden file** and **in windows 10 it is a configuration file** so it is most likely not recommended.try not to name a file starting with a literal '.' . it makes some weird system calls. so your file is not being syntax highlighted